# (SOLVED) One line on a line graph sits at the top of the graph, rather than follow its values

Tags: python, matplotlib, line

I have an 'average' (maybe slightly below) experience of matplotlib, but I'm absolutely confused by this. I have 3 lines on a graph, shown in the image, yet one line seems to want to stick to the top of the graph, even though its values are 0-4 and the graph is meant to be 0-10 vertically.
Anyone know what's going on?

```
time, mood, motiv, energy = self.CollectStatistics()
    y_ticks = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
    y_labels = ['0','1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
    plt.plot(time,mood,label="Mood",linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(time,motiv,label="Motivation",linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(time,energy,label="Energy",linewidth=2)
    plt.ylim(0,10)
    plt.yticks(ticks=y_ticks,label=y_labels)
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

[picture of my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKxHB.png)

The line in question is the third plot (label="Energy")

Comment: Your issue is caused by `plt.yticks(ticks=y_ticks,label=y_labels` which makes a mess of your ticks. Just use `plt.yticks(ticks=y_ticks)` if you only want to set specific positions. Matplotlib will put the correct corresponding labels automatically.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was the other two lines took ints yet the issue line was passing them as floats.
Converting to int seems to have solved it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).